# Using static List to keep all threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

Hi I want to use a static list to keep all running threads, like:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static final List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Thread(() -> {
            MyClass.threads.add(Thread.currentThread());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }).start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (!threads.isEmpty()) {
                Thread t = threads.get(0);
                System.out.println(t.isAlive());
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

The code above will give a print out of

```
true
true
false
false
...
```

This is as expected as after 2 sec the thread returns.

My question is: does the thread added to the static list of threads ever disappear after the thread has returned? i.e. do I expect to see the thread object inside the list becomes null at some point after the thread has returned? Or will I see the thread object indefinitely? Does GC play a part here?

Comment: *does the thread added to the static list of threads ever disappear after the thread has returned?* Only if you remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Thread object doesn't magically disappear once the associated OS thread terminates.

Once the thread is terminated it can't serve as a GC root, but as long as something else keeps a reference to it, like your list, it will stick around.

And it doesn't matter whether the thread is stopped or interrupted or whatever. The java.lang.Thread is an object that references a system resource, the actual thread, for as long as that thread is alive, but once the thread terminates that doesn't do anything to destroy the object. Just isAlive returns false and you can't successfully call start on it anymore.

It is hard to imagine what good it will do to keep a list of threads like what you propose.

Comment: Thank you. I am adding threads on construction of MyClass so that I know who holds an instance of it.

Comment: @user1589188: you'd be better off using a Thread pool rather than dedicated threads.

Comment: Thank you. Almost perfect answer. Now if I call remove to release the final reference to the thread object, then GC will reuse the resource occupied by the thread right?

Comment: @iser2589288: yes, if nothing else is holding onto a reference. You might check out weak references

Comment: Good Answer. [Learn about Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html), with thread pools, rather than managing explicit threads.

Comment: @user1589188: that’s what we call the [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/166789); instead of asking for your problem *x*, you are asking about your solution attempt *y*. Perhaps you open a new question for your *actual* problem.

Comment: @Holger perhaps by then some people will say "your question is too broad" or "show us what you have tried" :)

Comment: @user1589188: there is no problem with showing what you have tried, but the first thing of your question should be a description of what you are actually trying to achieve. You may also include a link to this question when explaining the failed attempt.

Answer (score 1):

No, the thread is no longer running but the `Thread` object you are holding on to will remain, just like any other object. The garbage collector can only clean up objects nothing has any references to, and `Thread` instances are no exception.